# Finding the runtime of a segment of code in C

Tags: c, runtime, clock

The below code should find the runtime in seconds of the for loop. Looking at other resources this should do the trick, having an initial `clock()` subracted from a `clock()` after the for loop runs. Any ideas why the code isn't working as written?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

//prototypes
int rfact(int n);
int temp = 0;

main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    double result = 0.0;
    clock_t t;
    printf("Enter a value for n: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    printf("n=%i\n", n);

    //get current time
    t = clock();

    //process factorial 2 million times
    for(i=0; i<2000000; i++)
    {
        rfact(n);
    }

    printf("n=%i\n", n);

    //get total time spent in the loop
    result = (double)((clock() - t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    //print result
    printf("runtime=%d\n", result);
}

//factorial calculation
int rfact(int n)
{

    if (n<=0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * rfact(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = (double)((clock() - t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

This should be:

```
result = ((double)(clock() - t))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Otherwise, you're doing integer division and converting the result to a double, which is not what you want.

Also:

```
printf("runtime=%d\n", result);
```

Should be:

```
printf("runtime=%f\n", result);
```

Comment: When I run it, I get a long number, after it finishes in milliseconds. The output switches between -343597384 and 1202590843 every other run

Comment: You have: `printf("runtime=%d\n", result);`. `%d` is for `int`s, but `result` is a float.